# How can I analyse the visibility of the urban area in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, analysis, arcscene, visibility

I want to analyse the visibility of the urban area using ArcMap. I saw the image below and I want to have the same output. Can you explain the process and steps to obtain this output?
[image]

Comment: Have you googled viewshed analysis?

Comment: Yes, I search it too much but the point is that viewshed is suitabe for large scale and it is often used to analyse mountain area not urban spaces.

Comment: Are you looking to do [this](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/skyline-analysis-an-urban-environmental-physical-design-aid.htm)?

Comment: I think the better way is Line of sight in Gis. But I need the process and steps to obtain to that output. I have read GIS help but It is general.